# This is my program for finding armstrong number

Tags: java

```
package armstrong;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class armstrong {
    static int tr;
    static double tri=0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
         int s;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        s=sc.nextInt();
        int b=s;


        do
        {   
            tr=s%10;
            tri=tri+Math.pow(tr,3);
            s=s/10;


        }
        while(s!=0);
            if(tri==b)
            System.out.println("the number is armstrong");
            else
                System.out.println("not armstrong");

    }

}
```

here i introduced a  variable 'b' because 's' will get modified during the do while loop.
is there any way to use 's' rather than storing the value to another variable

Comment: If you require two separate values then you need to have 2 variables - why do you not want to do that?

Comment: If you want to retain the original value, no, there is no other way. You could, however, modify `b` instead of `s`; this way, `s` always remains the number inputted by the user. Might be a bit easier to read this way. Even easier if you use variable names with more than two or three characters.

Comment: @tobias_k : There is. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. 
Do the following:

```
tr = s;

do
{   
    tri=tri+Math.pow(tr%10,3);
    tr=tr/10;
}
while(tr!=0);
```

And then,

```
if(tri==s)
    System.out.println("the number is armstrong");
else
    System.out.println("not armstrong");
```

Notice, I directly used `tr%10` in the computation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this program to get Armstrong number:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ArmstrongNumberChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = 0, a, temp,n;
        System.out.print("enter a number:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();
        temp = n;
        while (n > 0) {
            a = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
            c = c + (a * a * a);
        }
        if (temp == c) {
            System.out.println("armstrong number");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Not armstrong number");
        }
    }
}
```